# ASP.NET Web Custom Controls

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I am Beginner. I want to study and create custom controls. I have searched on Google but didn't find any good stuff.
Could anybody provide me some nice link or explain me that how can I start custom controls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Following article might help you :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/MyTextBox.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/EnhanceGrid.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is walkthrough in creating webserver control at MSDN  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx